# Zend default route masks invalid module

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

In application.ini I have default route:

```
resources.router.routes.default.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
resources.router.routes.default.route = ":lang/:module/:controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.module = "default"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.action = "index"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.lang = ""
```

The problem is that it seems this somehow masks 404 error on invalid module. For example on url like "/en/mmm" request is routed to default/index/index. However for "/en/mmm/ccc" invalid controller is triggered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

near as I can tell, that behavior is normal.

I've been looking at the docs and the code and it seems as though the router will load the default controller/action on a url like `/en/mmm`. The lang:en is valid but `mmm` doesn't match a valid module or controller so the default route is used.

In the case of `en/mmm/ccc` it does throw a 404 because in the absence of a valid module the route will be match against controller/action and because the values are not valid will result in a 404. I'm sure why this results in a 404 and an invalid controller just results in the default route being called.

This activity is demonstrated to degree in these examples from [Default Routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.default-routes):

```
 // Assuming the following: $ctrl->setControllerDirectory(
     array(
         'default' => '/path/to/default/controllers',
         'news'    => '/path/to/news/controllers',
         'blog'    => '/path/to/blog/controllers'
     ) );

 Module only: http://example/news
 //if not valid module would attempt to match controller.
 //if not valid controller would call default route
     module == news

 Invalid module maps to controller name: http://example/foo
     controller == foo

 Module + controller: http://example/blog/archive
     module     == blog
     controller == archive

 Module + controller + action: http://example/blog/archive/list
 //all three must be valid or 404
     module     == blog
     controller == archive
     action     == list

 Module + controller + action + params:
 http://example/blog/archive/list/sort/alpha/date/desc
     module     == blog
     controller == archive
     action     == list
     sort       == alpha
     date       == desc
```

The following code excerpt seems to be the best example I find of where this behavior is demonstrated.

```
//excerpt from Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Module

if ($this->_moduleValid || array_key_exists($this->_moduleKey, $data)) {
            if ($params[$this->_moduleKey] != $this->_defaults[$this->_moduleKey]) {
                $module = $params[$this->_moduleKey];
            }
        }
        unset($params[$this->_moduleKey]);

        $controller = $params[$this->_controllerKey];
        unset($params[$this->_controllerKey]);

        $action = $params[$this->_actionKey];
        unset($params[$this->_actionKey]);

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $key = ($encode) ? urlencode($key) : $key;
            if (is_array($value)) {
                foreach ($value as $arrayValue) {
                    $arrayValue = ($encode) ? urlencode($arrayValue) : $arrayValue;
                    $url .= self::URI_DELIMITER . $key;
                    $url .= self::URI_DELIMITER . $arrayValue;
                }
            } else {
                if ($encode) $value = urlencode($value);
                $url .= self::URI_DELIMITER . $key;
                $url .= self::URI_DELIMITER . $value;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($url) || $action !== $this->_defaults[$this->_actionKey]) {
            if ($encode) $action = urlencode($action);
            $url = self::URI_DELIMITER . $action . $url;
        }

        if (!empty($url) || $controller !== $this->_defaults[$this->_controllerKey]) {
            if ($encode) $controller = urlencode($controller);
            $url = self::URI_DELIMITER . $controller . $url;
        }

        if (isset($module)) {
            if ($encode) $module = urlencode($module);
            $url = self::URI_DELIMITER . $module . $url;
        }

        return ltrim($url, self::URI_DELIMITER);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm, since I want to have 404 in this situations I applied "dirty" solution in default module, index controller:
`public function indexAction()
  {
     if($this->getRequest()->getParam('module') != 'default'){
        throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception($this->translate("Page not found"),404);
     }
}`